# how to run some function right after facebook like box plugin is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

How to know if a facebook like box plugin has loaded successfully? I have to re-adjust layout if facebook like box plugin is loaded completely, I have included function to re-adjust layout in function `adjust_layout()` ...

So `adjust_layout()` function should run exactly after facebook like box plugins have successfully loaded?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the `xfbml.render` event – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.3:

> `xfbml.render` – Fired when FB.XFBML.parse() completes. This indicates that all of the social plugins on the page have been loaded.

By subscribing to that event, you can specify your function as the callback function to be called when the event fires.